# Does a network have more than 1 LIN master?

Tags: network-protocols

In a network, how many LIN masters can be there? There can be more than one LIN master? According to me, there will be only one LIN master and multiple slaves. Can anyone please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

As per the spec it is only one master and multiple slaves